# How to export all email contacts which are failed to send from email statistics

Tags: outbound-email

How to export only those contacts from email statistics which are failed or Action taken or read. I didn't found any option to export these contacts. I have read the documentation. Am I missing something in documentation. Please help me to export these contacts. And if this is not a tridion functionality then is there any way to add this functionality in our system.
   Your help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation topic "[Exporting Contacts from statistics](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-8E58CAD4-CABE-4247-AF95-F97DE2462092)".

Essentially, you select the status you want (e.g. "Failed"), optionally select a Distribution List to limit it to Contacts within that list, and then click Export Contacts in the toolbar.

Comment: If this is the right answer to your question... make sure to accept it then, for others to know it too.